# How to export custom parent pom properties to a file, from a child pom?

Tags: maven, ant, maven-plugin, maven-antrun-plugin

I have a parent pom with some custom properties and I would like to export those properties from one of the child to a file.

I tried maven-antrun-plugin with echo, but this works only with the child properties. I also tried to define child properties and assign the parent properties (e.g. `<child.prop>${parent.prop}</child.prop>`) but I got the same result.

Update:
It worked after I run mvn clean install on the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent custom properties are available in child pom only after mvn install on the parent.